# C++ "incomplete type is not allowed" when using stringstream

Tags: c++, clang, stringstream

I have the following C++ code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string sText = "These are words in my string!";
    std::string sWord;
    std::stringstream ss(sText);
}
```

And it works fine on Fedora with g++. However, running it on Windows with Visual Studio (so I guess clang) gets `incomplete type is not allowed`. Is this an error with my code, or is there some difference between compilers?
Note: I've tried `std::stringstream ss << sText;` but that gets the same exact error.

Comment: Why not trying to look for A in the stringstream manual and just posting Q on SO instead?

Comment: Include sstream

Comment: To use `std::stringstream`, you need to `#include <sstream>`.  All `std::` names live is particular header files.

Comment: And to use `std::string`, you need `#include <string>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've failed to `#include <sstream>`.

This is allowed to compile (any standard header can include an arbitrary number of other standard headers), but you should normally include the headers for the "stuff" you're using (and `stringstream` is declared in `<sstream>`). Once you include the header, VC++ compiles it just fine.

[Thanks Remy] Since you're using `std::string`, you should also `#include <string>`.

Comment: And along that same vein, you should `#include <string>` to use `std::string` properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: good point.

Comment: That works, but why does it get `incomplete type is not allowed`?

Comment: Apparently one of the headers you included declares but does not define `stringstream`, which makes it an incomplete type. You can define a pointer or reference to an incomplete type, but not define an instance of one.